# How to prevent Mercurial Commits containing string on Windows?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-hook

I'm looking to prevent commits to my local Windows Mercurial repo if the following string is present in any uncommitted files:

> DO NOT COMMIT ME

I know that the Pre-commit [hook I need](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) is `pretxncommit`. If I were on Linux I would just do something like this:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit.donotcommitme = hg export tip | (! grep -E -q -i 'do not commit me')
```

(Taken from [this link](https://coderwall.com/p/mfon-g/adding-a-pre-commit-hook-to-mercurial) but not verified/tested)

As a replacement for egrep, I've got `FINDSTR /I /C:"do not commit"`, which seems to work fine. However I can't find anything to "negate" its results like in the above Linux example.

As a possible alternative to pure Command Prompt commands, I've also ran across [this PowerShell script](http://www.ilovetodeletecode.com/post/2013/10/31/Prevent-large-file-commits-with-PowerShell-and-Mercurial-hooks) that checks for large binaries. But I do not know PowerShell, so this whole thing looks gibberish to me.

Does anyone know of a simple way to do what I'm after without installing Python, Cygwin, or anything else? Or do you know how to adapt the above PowerShell script to do string checking instead of file size checking?

We are also using TortoiseHG, so any solution may use that instead of pure Mercurial as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the PowerShell part was easier than I expected. I ended up just writing my own simple script based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jernejg/7196705).

Here it is for all who are intersted:

```
# This is like an "include" needed for the MessageBox
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

function Show-MessageBox()
{
    $message = "Found a ""DO NOT COMMIT ME"" message in your code!`r`n`r`nIf you are doing a pull or rebase this is probably okay.`r`n`r`nCommit anyway?"
    $title = "DO NOT COMMIT ME DETECTED!"
    $buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::YesNo
    $icon = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon]::Warning

    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show($message, $title, $buttons, $icon)
}

# Use `hg export` to search for the string "do not commit me" (case insensitive)
write "Checking for DO NOT COMMIT ME comments in your code..."
$whoops = (hg export tip | Select-String -pattern "do not commit me");

# If we have it in our changeset, abort the commit!
if ($whoops)
{
    $a = Show-MessageBox

    if ($a -eq "Yes")
    {
        write "`r`n!!! COMMITING ANYWAY !!!`r`n"
        exit 0
    }

    write "`r`n*** ABORTING COMMIT! ***`r`n"
    exit 1
}

write "Okay to commit!"
exit 0
```

NOTE: I also had to turn on the ability to run PowerShell scripts with `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (while running PowerShell as Administrator). The command-line `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` flag did NOT work correctly and caused all kinds of problems in TortoiseHG!